Opening web browser from flutter app and then redirecting to app again
I am redirecting from a web browser to my Flutter application using a redirect URL, which also has a code with it.  I am facing the following error when redirecting back to my app:

PlatformException(null_intent, Failed to authorize: Null intent received, null, null)

while my redirect URL is: com.example.crewdogcvlab://redirect
E/flutter (22869): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null_intent, Failed to authorize: Null intent received, null, null)
E/flutter (22869): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:651:7)
E/flutter (22869): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:322:18)
E/flutter (22869): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22869): #2      MethodChannelFlutterAppAuth.authorize (package:flutter_appauth_platform_interface/src/method_channel_flutter_appauth.dart:21:9)
E/flutter (22869): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22869): #3      loginAction (package:crewdogcvlab/screens/controllers/sso_authentication.dart:22:18)
E/flutter (22869): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22869): #4      _WelcomeScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:crewdogcvlab/screens/welcome_screen.dart:85:29)
E/flutter (22869): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (22869): 


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Align the redirectUri (used to call the service) and the custom URL (or universal link) defined in the AndroidManifest.xml (and check that you have not repeated the same custom URL/universal link in several places in your AndroidManifest.xml)
